# Redirect AJAX query by .htaccess

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, redirect

I have a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex control.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) controller.php?do=$1 [L]
```

This redirects all queries and sets up clean URLs. But when I use ajax it redirects that too. Is it possible to filter ajax queries and redirect to

```
controller-ajax.php?do=$1 [L]
```

instead?

I was trying to catch it in controller.php, but `X_REQUESTED_WITH` doesn't exist. The best thing then would be to redirect to another script all ajax requests, and not make an additional script check.

Comment: Is there a way you can make the AJAX queries be different from other types of queries? Perhaps add a GET variable like `?ajax=true`?

Comment: Thanks for answering.But it also possible to call script by adding this variable to simple http query, and you ll be passed, and js function is not so hard to find for getting this variable

Comment: Any ideas please, im trying to fix it about several weeks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call AJAX, add a GET variable to the query (i.e. add `?ajax=true` to the end of the query). Then have this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex control.php
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f {OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ajax.true
RewriteRule (.+) controller-ajax.php?do=$1 [L]

RewriteRule (.+) controller.php?do=$1 [L]
```

Comment: But does it makes any defense? I also can look by network activity where and what i have queried, and just add to simple link ?ajax=true and ill get script, which i want to protect, Maybe by header is possible to avoid it?

Comment: Can you try checking for this variable instead? `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` (should be 'XMLHttpRequest') - some servers send it, some don't. Also I didn't realize you were trying to protect the script file. I will say though that you can't protect it 100% - given that AJAX is a client-side request, someone smart enough can always mimic such a request.

Comment: dunno why but $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] is not exists oO i think using byte encrypting with small shuffle function would be enough to remove large amount of non waiting guests.

Comment: It will make things a little more difficult, but the script will still be accessible. It just depends on how hard you want to make it.