# AJAX POST request does not work properly along with .htaccess redirect rule

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file. As it can be seen everything is redirected through index.php.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /project_name/public
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now this is a file (viewname.php) located in one of my views folder (this is a MVC styled project). Here as it can be seen I am making an AJAX POST request, to a file ajax.php located in the same folder as index.php (i.e., folder public). Notice that I'm not writing the url as "../something", as I'm redirecting everything through index.php. I confirmed that by writing `<?php echo __FILE__;?>`, in this file, which returned the result index.php. If the AJAX request is successful, I should get the output as "Working" in the div with id 'r'. But that does not happen. Also I do not get any error like *jquery.min.js:4 POST http://127.0.0.1/project_name/public/file_name.php 404 (Not Found)* in the console, which I used to get in a project without that .htaccess file. When I `console.log(data)` I see the HTML code in the index.php file, which in this case are CDNs for Bootstrap and JQuery, in the console. What changes should I make to my AJAX code or .htaccess file?

```
<div id="r"></div>

//JQuery AJAX
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({
  url: "ajax.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
   valid: "yes"
  },
  success: function(data){
  $("div#r").html(data);
  }
 });
});
```

This is the code in the ajax.php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['valid'])){
 if($_POST['valid']=='yes'){
  echo 'Working';
 }
}
```

Comment: What URL are you actually _on_ when you make the AJAX request? (This sounds like the typical newbie problem of not being aware how relative URLs work, tbh.)

Comment: Actually I used to use the url: "ajax.php", but later I switched it to "http://127.0.0.1/project_name/ajax.php", and everything is working fine now. By the way @CBroe do you have any link that can solve my URL problems there are plenty of those??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the url from "ajax.php" to "http://127.0.0.1/project_name/ajax.php", and everything is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

you missing function after ()(round bracket)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $.ajax({
          url: "test1.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: {
           valid: "yes"
          },
          success: function(data){
          $("div#r").html(data);
          }
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in this case the AJAX works completely but the only difference is that the ajax cannot make a difference to your webpage like echo,call the function,etc.

Comment: ANy solution to what you said?

Comment: you can pass the values in the url of the page to another one.

Comment: Can you please elaborate??

Comment: i meant to say that you can send the data by using `<form> action ="" </form>` and it will give you result as desired.

Comment: So what is the purpose of using AJAX at all, if I use <form>?

Comment: An explanation to my answer is,AJAX is relates to javascript which is used for  frontend processing and php is a backend language and hence their cannot be any co-relation between them ever.ajax just interacts with the server request.

Comment: Okay.. I thought I could have modified my .htaccess file as mentioned  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708273/redirect-ajax-query-by-htaccess

Comment: the above mentioned link is only for the data which you pass by ajax into the url itself.

Comment: kindof this link answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651656/passing-multiple-parameters-with-ajax-url

Comment: if my answer helped you in any way can you please accept it?

Comment: Nope.I believed there must be some get-around, and I've found it. And that is the reason why I didn't accept your answer.